# Create duplicate rows based on conditions in R

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like this

```
dt <- data.table(ID=c("A","A","B","B"),Amount1=c(100,200,300,400),
                 Amount2=c(1500,1500,2400,2400),Dupl=c(1,0,1,0))

   ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
1:  A     100    1500    1
2:  A     200    1500    0
3:  B     300    2400    1
4:  B     400    2400    0
```

I need to duplicate each row that has a 1 in the Dupl column and replace the Amount1 value with the Amount2 value in that duplicated row. Besides that I need to give that duplicated row the value 2 in Dupl. This means it should look like this:

```
   ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
1:  A     100    1500    1
2:  A    1500    1500    2
3:  A     200    1500    0
4:  B     300    2400    1
5:  B    2400    2400    2
6:  B     400    2400    0
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Kind regards,

Tim

Comment: Are there any other rules we need to know? Could there be four rows for a given ID? Does the "Dupl" column have values other than "1" and "2"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try

```
rbind(dt,dt[Dupl==1][,c('Amount1', 'Dupl') := list(Amount2, 2)])
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I was also thinking in terms of `rleid` using your template code, but found to be a bit difficult.

Comment: How do you generalize this?
For example my data.table has a column defining groups. I want to duplicate each whole group N times, where N is calculated as a function of some column.

Comment: @skan can you post as a question so that it becomes more easier to understand

Answer (score 15):

Using *dplyr*

```
library("dplyr")

rbind(dt,
      dt %>% 
        filter(Dupl == 1) %>% 
        mutate(Dupl = 2,
               Amount1 = Amount2))

#    ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
# 1:  A     100    1500    1
# 2:  A     200    1500    0
# 3:  B     300    2400    1
# 4:  B     400    2400    0
# 5:  A    1500    1500    2
# 6:  B    2400    2400    2
```

Comment: I always try to avoid plyr since I work with large datasets, but this worked as well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can `rbind` a copy of the sub-setted data with the correct transformations done:

```
rbind(dt,copy(dt[Dupl==1])[,Amount1:=Amount2][,Dupl:=Dupl+1])
   ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
1:  A     100    1500    1
2:  A     200    1500    0
3:  B     300    2400    1
4:  B     400    2400    0
5:  A    1500    1500    2
6:  B    2400    2400    2
```

Alternatively, you can get the duplicates by sub-setting, and then transform the duplicated rows using an intermediate step. This keeps the duplicated row next to the original as in the example in the question:

```
x <- dt[rep(seq(dt[,Dupl]),times=dt[,Dupl==1]+1)]
x[duplicated(x),c("Amount1","Dupl"):=list(Amount2,Dupl+1)]
x
   ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
1:  A     100    1500    1
2:  A    1500    1500    2
3:  A     200    1500    0
4:  B     300    2400    1
5:  B    2400    2400    2
6:  B     400    2400    0
```

Comment: You can do the first step in the second solution just by `x <- dt[rep(seq_len(.N), Dupl + 1L)]`. It seems like calling `dt` 3 times in this single step is a big overhead if `dt` is big.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do what you are asking for. Can probably be refined a bit...

```
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(dt, dt$Dupl+1, count.is.col = FALSE)[
  Dupl != 0, Dupl := cumsum(Dupl), by = ID][
    , Amount1 := ifelse(Dupl > 1, Amount2[-1], Amount1)][]
#    ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
# 1:  A     100    1500    1
# 2:  A    1500    1500    2
# 3:  A     200    1500    0
# 4:  B     300    2400    1
# 5:  B    2400    2400    2
# 6:  B     400    2400    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr's `left_join` to do the duplication work. Perhaps not elegant, but should be easy to understand.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

joiner <- data.frame(Dupl = 1, helper_col= 1:2)

dt <- left_join(dt, joiner) %>%
  mutate(Dupl = ifelse(helper_col == 2 & !is.na(helper_col), 2, Dupl)) %>%
  select(-helper_col) %>%
  mutate(Amount1 = ifelse(Dupl == 2, Amount2, Amount1))

> dt
  ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
1  A     100    1500    1
2  A    1500    1500    2
3  A     200    1500    0
4  B     300    2400    1
5  B    2400    2400    2
6  B     400    2400    0
```

Comment: This solution is simple and understandable.  It is also more flexible imho than the others because one can easily adapt the joiner data frame to handle different scenarios where you might want more than one duplication, e.g. expanding quarters into months.  Viewing years later, I found this to be the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

Biased here, but I think this dplyr solution is elegant, and it's also pretty scalable, especially as long as `Dupl` is always <= 2. Essentially, it takes advantage of `tidyr::uncount`, which says, 'Based on a given column's value (x), repeat each row x times, thereby elongating the df.' Once we've lengthened the df, we can just use `dplyr::mutate_at` to replace cells if they're the same value as their lag.

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>%
    uncount(Dupl + 1) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Amount1),
              ~case_when(. == lag(.) ~ Amount2, TRUE ~.)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Dupl),
              ~case_when(. == lag(.) ~ 2, TRUE ~.))

#    ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
# 1:  A     100    1500    1
# 2:  A    1500    1500    2
# 3:  A     200    1500    0
# 4:  B     300    2400    1
# 5:  B    2400    2400    2
# 6:  B     400    2400    0
```